# Unable to assign a certain pixel value to an image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I assign a certain pixel intensity to a pixel value (255,0,0). I then save that image and reload it to find where that pixel intensity value is with numpy but I end up getting an empty array as output.

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2

#read an img
img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')

#assign pixel value
img[779,804] = (255,0,0)

#save img
cv2.imwrite('new_img.jpg', img)
read_img = cv2.imread('new_img.jpg')
intensity_val = np.where((read_img [:,:,0]==255)&(read_img [:,:,1]==0)&(read_img [:,:,2]==0))
print(intensity_val)
```

The output I get is:

(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))

I don't know why the output is empty array.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy codec. Use a lossless one, like PNG.

Comment: I tried saving that to a PNG but the results are still the same

Comment: Works fine for me, if I add the missing import of numpy and change both the `imwrite` and `imread` to use PNG. [Edit] your question and update the [mcve] to match current state of your code, and make sure it actually does what you say (this one can't, due to the missing import).

Comment: there is no issue. your picture simply does not contain anything that is blue. imread() returns colors in BGR order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who is curious, changing the extension of an image from .jpg to .png did the job.

Comment: I really hope you mean saving the data as a different format. simply renaming an existing file to give it a different suffix will not alter its contents.